# Menu fade in (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, effect

Im trying to figure out how could I make the menu on my website fade in.
I would like it so each menu item fades in individually. So when item 1 is nearly faded in item 2 starts fading in and so on. How would I do this using Javascript or JQuery?

Comment: @trojansdestroy I have tried nothing yet. I'm not to familiar with JS.

Comment: Post your HTML then, and describe specifically which elements you want to change.

Comment: Checkout the .fadeIn(); jQuery method. Wrap it in a $(function(), and when you are ready, get in a for loop and fadeIn(); each element with the counter loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this. Fade-in menu using html,css and jquery

```
  $("#menu li").hover(

      function () {
        $(this).children("ul").finish().fadeIn();
      },
      function () {
         $(this).children("ul").finish().delay(1000).fadeOut();
  });
```

[Jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/dXAcR/1/)

Comment: Not Quite, Instead of the Sub menus fading in, I would like the menu to fade in on load.

Comment: If you want menu fadeIn on load of page then you can do it on document.ready() like this      `$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#menu").delay(1000).fadeIn();
});`